# Xamarin Forms MediaManager Source property

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin and Xamarin Forms.  I am using the Sample form MediaManager https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager.  It works with the sample url, but I can't get it to work with a local resource for either iOS or Android.

Comment: I believe you need to open a stream to the local resource/file and pass that in to MediaManager

Comment: The source property is a string.

Comment: I stand corrected - from reviewing their github issues it sounded like that was an option.  I'd post an issue on GitHub requesting an example of playing a local file/resource

Answer (score 1):

I've only tested this in iOS so far but place the file in your Resources directory.

Then use this code to play the file.

iOS

```
await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play("myfile.mp3", MediaFileType.Audio, ResourceAvailability.Local);
```

Android: 
Place file in Resource/raw folder.
Do not add file extension to name.

```
await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play("android.resource://[PackageName]/raw/myfile", MediaFileType.Audio, ResourceAvailability.Local);
```