# Xamarin forms CrossMediaManager play from resource

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to play mp3 from my resource with CrossMediaManager  i have tried

```
await  CrossMediaManager.Current.Play("file:///AV.Droid/Resources/raw/gong.mp3");
 await  CrossMediaManager.Current.Play("file:///AV.Droid/Resources/raw/gong.mp3");
await  CrossMediaManager.Current.Play("file:///android_assets/gong.mp3");
 await CrossMediaManager.Current.PlayFromResource("gong.mp3"); as Android resource in drawable
```

based on this [Xamarin Forms MediaManager Source property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43103089/xamarin-forms-mediamanager-source-property)

the methods doest take 3 parameters anymore so i have tried this

```
await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play("android.resource://[PackageName]/raw/myfile";
```

and from shared

```
await  CrossMediaManager.Current.Play("gong.mp3"); saved as embeded resouce
```

Comment: none of your examples match the two solutions provided in the linked question

Comment: well that is because the linked question is also a bit older, and the methods dont take 3 parameters anymore.

Comment: I’ve never used this plugin, but the doc at its github shows a PlayFromResource method. Isn’t that what you want?

Comment: i have tried that now too, for some reason still nothing

Comment: did you follow their example when specifying the resource name?  https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager#other-play-possibilities

Comment: *"i have tried that now too"*. Its important to add to question **exactly** the code that you tried.